# If $\frac{a-b}{c-d} = 3$ and $\frac{a-c}{b-d} = 4$, what’s $\frac{a-d}{c-b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $\dfrac{a-b}{c-d} = 3$ and $\dfrac{a-c}{b-d} = 4$, what’s $\dfrac{a-d}{c-b}$?

I am not a math teacher but I am teaching a child the basics, I tried approaching this tenth grade question using systems but the result is not a real number.

Comment: What was the result you got. You also need to include your steps used, or no one can help.

Comment: You mean $(a - b)/(c - d)=3,$ not $a-(b/c)-d = 3,$ right?

Comment: Solve simultaneously to get $a$ and $d$ each in terms of $b$ and $c$ only, then work out $a-d$. It all works out fine…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating the value of $\frac{a-d}{b-c}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021567/calculating-the-value-of-fraca-db-c)

Answer (score 4):

From given equation we have

\begin{align} a-b &=3c-3d\\ a-c &=4b-4d
\end{align}
So if we subtrak these two we get
$$ d =3b-2c$$ and thus $$ a =9c-8b$$

So if we put these two in to the starting expression we get $${a-d\over c-b}=11$$

Comment: Well, you could elaborate on your steps a bit more...